# Outlook Focused Inbox Disappearing - Need to Fix

Tags: windows-10, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

The focused inbox in my outlook office 365 has suddenly disappeared after some update or not sure. I have bring the Focused button to be viewed but with empty button as per the image

This disappearing happened suddenly after long use of Outlook. However, when I restart the Outlook the button get back for a while and then disappear again.

Please advise your suggestions.

[image: Focused Empty Button Image]

Comment: Your image is missing.

Comment: I have uploaded the image

Comment: I think I found the resolution here! I just removed the outlook profile from Control Panel > Mail > Profiles and then open the outlook and reconnect to my office 365 email again. I created a new outlook profile when outlook asked me a name of the profile and it worked well!!

Answer (score 0):

Is this the similar issue as your?

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/5b20ec4e-b2eb-412f-bc6d-730da2251641/outlook-2016-option-to-turn-onoff-focused-inbox-is-missing?forum=outlook

If so, please make sure you have upgraded your Outlook 365 to the latest version.

Besides, you could also try to Right click on the Ribbon > click "customize the Ribbon" choose Reset to reset all customization and restart your Outlook to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestion of the OP in his comment, I resolved the exact same problem on my Windows 10 laptop by creating a new Outlook Profile, and then adding my email account(s) to this new profile.  No other solutions in the existing profile would persist past the first attempt to search.

To create a new profile, go to Control Panel (small icons view) -> Mail (Microsoft Outlook); select 'Profiles / Show Profiles', then add a new profile, and make it the default (I prefer not to delete the existing profile in case there are settings / configs of value there. There's no reason other than space not to create a new one, leaving the old profile in place as a backup/reference).  Next, open Outlook, and add the office 365 mail account(s). I had two separate accounts (both office 365 mailboxes) and they both configured fine, and 'focused view' is now working for both.

Comment: Still working almost 3 weeks later, after 6 months of trying everything else! I'm a happy camper.

Answer (score 0):

This same issue happens to me and others in my organization. The following get messed up in Outlook:

1. Focused mode becomes unavailable.
2. Access to Public Folders becomes unavailable.
3. Outlook Shortcuts pointing to public folders disappear.
4. Restarting Outlook shows the Public Folders and Focused mode for about a minute, then they disappear.

This has been ongoing and no amount of research and talking to Microsoft has found us a resolution to this annoying problem.

Solution we devised:

1. In Control Panel > Mail, delete the current Outlook profile and create a new one.
2. Configure Outlook settings and preferences including the shortcuts.
3. Copy the "good" Outlook profile and call it Outlook-Template.
4. If you use Outlook shortcuts, save a copy of Outlook.xml in C:\Users%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook.
5. Next time the Public Folders and Focused mode disappears, close Outlook.
6. In Control Panel > Mail, delete the default Outlook profile, copy the Outlook-Template profile and name it Outlook.
7. If you use shortcuts, copy the Outlook-Template.xml you backed up in item 4 above into Outlook.xml.
8. Start Outlook and voila, it is back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this issue now has an entry on Microsoft's learning website:  [Focused Inbox disappears when you switch folders in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/profiles-and-accounts/focused-inbox-disappears-switch-folder).  Here's a summary of the article:

**Symptom**

You set up a Microsoft 365 account in Microsoft Outlook. When you switch from the Inbox to other folders, such as the Sent Items folder, and then you return to Inbox, the Focused Inbox option disappears. Additionally, the option on the View tab to turn on or off the Focused Inbox also disappears.

**Cause**

This issue occurs because the Autodiscover process that's used by Outlook did not retrieve the XML from Microsoft 365, and received an unexpected result from a third-party web server that uses IMAP settings.

**Resolution**

Contact your web service provider or the web hosting provider of your domain website to make sure that the web server isn't responding to the following Autodiscover requests:

- `https://<Rootdomain>/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml`
- `https://autodiscover.<Rootdomain>/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml`.

**Workaround**

To work around this issue, exclude the Last Known Good URL by creating this registry key with a value of 1:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\x.0\Outlook\AutoDiscoverExcludeLastKnownGoodURL`

Note that because excluding the Last Known Good URL isn't a long-term solution for this issue, Microsoft recommends that as soon as the web service provider or web hosting provider fixes the issue, this registry key should be removed.